# jquery moving rows between table disables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

Im moving rows between tables, it seems to works fine but once the row is in the other table all javascript functions related to that row no longer work and I have no idea why.

The javascript is pretty straight forward I take the html for the row and move it into the other table.

**If you click the child tabs they work fine, but click on waitlist (or approve to move to the table above) to move it to the below table and the tabs for that row no longer work.**

The weird thing is no error is thrown, and nothing is logged in the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ha3Jq/16/

### Jquery

```
$( ".enrolled-participants" ).on("click","button.remove-participant",function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('remove-participant')) 
    {
       $(this).html('Approve');
       $(this).removeClass('remove-participant').addClass('add-participant');
       var className = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
       var childClass =$(this).closest('tr').next().attr('class');
       var current_row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
       var child_row = $(this).closest('tr').next().html();
         $(this).closest('tr').next().remove();
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
         $('.waitlisted > tbody:last').append('<tr class="'+className+'">'+current_row+'</tr><tr class="'+childClass+'">'+child_row+'</tr>');
     }
```

Im also using the table sorter plugin.

### tablesorter

```
    $(".enrolled-participants,.waitlisted")
        .tablesorter({
            theme : 'blue',
            // this is the default setting
            cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",

            // initialize zebra and filter widgets
            widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],

            widgetOptions: {
                // include child row content while filtering, if true
                filter_childRows  : true,
                // class name applied to filter row and each input
                filter_cssFilter  : 'tablesorter-filter',
                // search from beginning
                filter_startsWith : false,
                // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive 
                filter_ignoreCase : true
            }

        });

    // hide child rows
    //$('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();

    // Toggle child row content (td), not hiding the row since we are using rowspan
    // Using delegate because the pager plugin rebuilds the table after each page change
    // "delegate" works in jQuery 1.4.2+; use "live" back to v1.3; for older jQuery - SOL
    $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click' ,function(){
//alert('ok');
        // use "nextUntil" to toggle multiple child rows
        // toggle table cells instead of the row
        $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.tablesorter-childRow)').find('td').toggle();

        return false;
    });

    // Toggle widgetFilterChildRows option
    $('button.toggle-option').click(function(){
        var c = $('.tablesorter')[0].config.widgetOptions,
        o = !c.filter_childRows;
        c.filter_childRows = o;
        $('.state').html(o.toString());
        // update filter; include false parameter to force a new search
        $('input.tablesorter-filter').trigger('search', false);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I'm not sure what this is supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: @paulDraper In the fiddle click on waitlist or approve buttons and now look at the tabs "general information" "medical information" for the row you moved , notice how they do not work anymore.

Comment: What should they do when I click them?

Comment: @PaulDraper anything really in this case they change the heading, but once you move a row between tables they don't work anymore even the hover effect is gone(for the tabs)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

`remove` removes it from the DOM, and it removes all of the (JavaScript) event listeners.

`detach` simply removes it from the DOM; the event listeners are left intact.

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not fix the issue.